# Calculate Actual Downtime ignoring overlap in dates/times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to work out how to calculate actual downtime for various applications from data I'm storing within a table.

At the moment I'm just calculating the difference between DowntimeStart and DowntimeEnd which is shown in the DowntimeMinutes.

The problem is that if there is a cross-over in times as separate components are down, it should count the total ignoring the over-lap.

What I expect is shown in the Expected column.

Any ideas on how a query could be put together to achieve this?

```
Application         DowntimeStart           DowntimeEnd              DowntimeMinutes    Expected
Application Demo    2014-11-20 17:31:01.467 2014-11-20 18:01:01.243  30                 30
Application Demo    2014-11-28 17:59:00.987 2014-11-28 18:09:02.167  10                 26
Application Demo    2014-11-28 18:00:01.403 2014-11-28 18:25:01.443  25                 0
Application Demo    2014-11-29 19:13:08.580 2014-11-30 05:30:01.763  617                617
Application Demo    2014-11-30 01:55:01.953 2014-11-30 03:54:01.730  119                0
```

I've taken a look and investigated these options but they don't achieve the above:

[Find Total Minutes Ignoring Overlap (Convert Cursor based Answer to CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482921/find-total-minutes-ignoring-overlap-convert-cursor-based-answer-to-cte)

[SQL to find time elapsed from multiple overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224792/sql-to-find-time-elapsed-from-multiple-overlapping-intervals)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/SQL_Server_2008/Q_28169653.html

http://thehobt.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/calculating-elapsed-time-based-upon.html

https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/duration-calculation-between-dates-which-has-overlap-with-other-date-ranges-for-same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED WITH NEW TEST CASES**

Here is one technique that calculates the unique outages and then aligns them back to the initial downtime causing the outage so that the actual and expected values match.

```
DECLARE @Downtime TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Application VARCHAR(25), 
    DowntimeStart DATETIME,
    DowntimeEnd DATETIME,
    Expected INT
)

INSERT @Downtime (Application, DowntimeStart, DowntimeEnd, Expected) VALUES -- Act/Exp
    ('Application Demo', '2014-11-20 17:31:01.467', '2014-11-20 18:01:01.243', 30) -- 30/30
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-28 17:59:00.987', '2014-11-28 18:09:02.167', 26) -- 10/26
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-28 18:00:01.403', '2014-11-28 18:25:01.443', 0) -- 25/0
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-29 19:13:08.580', '2014-11-30 05:30:01.763', 617) -- 617/617
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-30 01:55:01.953', '2014-11-30 03:54:01.730', 0)
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 3514)
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0)
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) 
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0)
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) 

SELECT
    Downtimes.Application,
    Downtimes.DowntimeStart,
    Downtimes.DowntimeEnd,
    Downtimes.Expected,
    COALESCE(Actual, 0) AS Actual
FROM @Downtime Downtimes
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            D1.Application,
            MIN(CASE WHEN D1.DowntimeStart < D2.DowntimeStart THEN D1.ID ELSE D2.ID END) AS [ID],
            MIN(CASE WHEN D1.DowntimeStart < D2.DowntimeStart THEN D1.DowntimeStart ELSE D2.DowntimeStart END) AS [DowntimeStart],
            MAX(CASE WHEN D1.DowntimeEnd > D2.DowntimeEnd THEN D1.DowntimeEnd ELSE D2.DowntimeEnd END) AS [DowntimeEnd],
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                MIN(CASE WHEN D1.DowntimeStart < D2.DowntimeStart THEN D1.DowntimeStart ELSE D2.DowntimeStart END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN D1.DowntimeEnd > D2.DowntimeEnd THEN D1.DowntimeEnd ELSE D2.DowntimeEnd END)) AS Actual
        FROM @Downtime D1
            INNER JOIN @Downtime D2
                ON D1.Application = D2.Application
                    AND (D1.DowntimeStart BETWEEN D2.DowntimeStart AND D2.DowntimeEnd
                        OR D2.DowntimeStart BETWEEN D1.DowntimeStart AND D1.DowntimeEnd)
        GROUP BY
            D1.Application,
            D1.DowntimeStart
    ) Outages
        ON Outages.ID = Downtimes.ID
```

And this yields the desired output:

```
Application               DowntimeStart           DowntimeEnd             Expected    Actual
------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
Application Demo          2014-11-20 17:31:01.467 2014-11-20 18:01:01.243 30          30
Application Demo          2014-11-28 17:59:00.987 2014-11-28 18:09:02.167 26          26
Application Demo          2014-11-28 18:00:01.403 2014-11-28 18:25:01.443 0           0
Application Demo          2014-11-29 19:13:08.580 2014-11-30 05:30:01.763 617         617
Application Demo          2014-11-30 01:55:01.953 2014-11-30 03:54:01.730 0           0
Application Demo 2        2014-12-19 23:09:01.303 2014-12-22 09:43:01.397 3514        3514
Application Demo 2        2014-12-19 23:09:01.303 2014-12-22 09:43:01.397 0           0
Application Demo 2        2014-12-19 23:09:01.303 2014-12-22 09:43:01.397 0           0
Application Demo 2        2014-12-19 23:09:01.303 2014-12-22 09:43:01.397 0           0
Application Demo 2        2014-12-19 23:09:01.303 2014-12-22 09:43:01.397 0           0
```

Comment: Minor data validation issue here: The last row's start time is between the previous row's start and end times, and thus should have affected both durations.

Comment: Thanks very much Jason, there's a problem I didn't consider though until I tested with all data. If you have the following, see next message, it returns the same value for all. Anyway to modify the query to take this into account?

Comment: INSERT #TABLENAME (Application, DowntimeStart, DowntimeEnd, Expected) VALUES -
    ('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 3514)
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) 
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) 
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) -
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0)

Comment: Does your table have a primary key that can be used for the change?

Comment: Yes it does. Is just straight named "ID" and is of type INT.

Comment: Ok, just updated answer to address additional test case.

Comment: Thanks very much Jason, much appreciated. Apologies for the late reply too, I was away over the Xmas/NY period. One final point if you don't mind? I've changed your query slightly to get a summary of the totals. 
    Downtimes.Application,
    sum(Actual) AS Actual
In doing this though, I need to get a total of 0 for those applications that don't have a record within the Downtime table.

How could that be done using a lookup? i.e.  Thanks

INSERT Applications (Application) VALUES 
    ('Application Demo') 
    ,('Application Demo 2') 
    ,('Application Demo 3') 
    ,('Application Demo 4')

Comment: If you have an Applications table, then LEFT OUTER JOIN Applications to your downtime table, and then COALESCE or ISNULL the downtime value with 0 if the value is NULL (ie: `COALESCE(DATEDIFF(...), 0)`)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I got it answered in my question [How to Consolidate Blocks of Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611687/calculate-actual-downtime-ignoring-overlap-in-dates-times)

In your case, this is accomplished with a top 1 self outer apply to get the overlap, and then use either the Overlap's Start time, or if null, the normal Record's end time as the end time.

```
CREATE TABLE Downtime (
    Application VARCHAR(25), 
    DowntimeStart DATETIME,
    DowntimeEnd DATETIME,
    Expected INT
)

INSERT Downtime (Application, DowntimeStart, DowntimeEnd, Expected) VALUES -- Act/Exp
    ('Application Demo', '2014-11-20 17:31:01.467', '2014-11-20 18:01:01.243', 30) -- 30/30
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-28 17:59:00.987', '2014-11-28 18:09:02.167', 26) -- 10/26
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-28 18:00:01.403', '2014-11-28 18:25:01.443', 0) -- 25/0
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-29 19:13:08.580', '2014-11-30 05:30:01.763', 617) -- 617/617
    ,('Application Demo', '2014-11-30 01:55:01.953', '2014-11-30 03:54:01.730', 0)


SELECT
    Records.Application, Records.DowntimeStart, Records.DowntimeEnd, Records.Expected
  , DATEDIFF(minute, Records.DowntimeStart, COALESCE(Overlap.DowntimeStart, Records.DowntimeEnd)) AS Actual
--  , Overlap.Application, Overlap.DowntimeStart, Overlap.DowntimeEnd -- For Verification Purposes
FROM Downtime Records
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Overlap.Application, Overlap.DowntimeStart, Overlap.DowntimeEnd
    FROM Downtime Overlap
    WHERE Records.Application = Overlap.Application
      AND Overlap.DowntimeStart > Records.DowntimeStart
      AND Overlap.DowntimeStart BETWEEN Records.DowntimeStart AND Records.DowntimeEnd
    ORDER BY Overlap.DowntimeStart
    ) Overlap
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b862/2) with the solution.

Comment: Thanks very much Jaaz, there's a problem I didn't consider though until I tested with all data. If you have the following, see next message, it returns the same value for all. Anyway to modify the query to take this into account?

Comment: INSERT #TABLENAME (Application, DowntimeStart, DowntimeEnd, Expected) VALUES -
    ('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 3514)
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) 
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) 
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0) -
    ,('Application Demo 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397', 0)