# How to sum UNIQUE total duarion in minutes from timestamp- sql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.3

I have following case scenario:

My table has following columns: ID, ClientName(String), StartTime (timestamp), EndTime (timestamp).

My goal is to sum duration for each Client e.g. for the last day, assuming that in one time period can be few values and I must have only real duration.

e.g. Content of table:

```
|Client1    |   2017-01-01 08:00:00      |   2017-01-01 08:05:00|
|Client1    |   2017-01-01 08:00:00      |   2017-01-01 08:10:00|
```

I am using following query for this example:

```
Select ClientName, SUM(date_trunc('second',coalesce(EndTime,now()::timestamp(0))-StartTime)) as duration 
from table 
group by ClientName
```

Result of above query is 15 but is should be 10. The same period of the time shouldn't be calculate.

Any ideas how to get correct results in PostgreSQL?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: ... or postgre?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Nitpicking:  [Use Postgres instead of Postgre](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info)

Comment: @wingedpanther will do.

Comment: What is the expected output based on your sample data?

Comment: Should be in PostgreSQL

Comment: So what is the result (=output) you expect?

Comment: Output should be: Sum of total duration group by client name.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention which database your are using , the implementation for each one of them is different, but with the same logic,

for Postgresql
i use row_number to remove the incorrect rows

```
    select ClientName,
           SUM(date_trunc('second',coalesce(EndTime,now()::timestamp(0))-StartTime)) as duration,
           SUM(datediff(minute,StartTime,EndTIme)) as Duration2
    from(
    select ClientName,
           StartTime,
           EndTIme,
           row_number () over ( partition by ClientName,StartTime order by EndTime desc) as rank
    from table) a
    where rank=1
    group by ClientName
```

Comment: I think there is not "wrong" rows, just overlapping rows

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. Executed your example but it giving me error: {{ ERROR: syntax error at or near "end"}}

Comment: try know ,i've added the end by mistake

Comment: Thanks, I checked and now I have syntax error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "table"

Comment: put your table name, and remove the alias

Comment: When I have following data in my table `1 Test 2017-01-01 10:40:00 2017-01-01 10:50:00 2 Test 2017-01-01 10:45:00 2017-01-01 10:48:00` it shows 13 minutes, which is incorrect. Should be 10 minutes.

Comment: very strange,pls try it know , i've changed the StartDate to EndTime in the order by, also you can use datediff to calculate the duration, try sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,EndTime)

Comment: Unfortunately *datediff* doesn't work.  ERROR: column "minute" does not exist. I tried using apostrophe for word minute but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from reference [Calculate Actual Downtime ignoring overlap in dates/times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611687/calculate-actual-downtime-ignoring-overlap-in-dates-times)

```
DECLARE @clientUsage TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ClientName VARCHAR(25), 
    StartTime  DATETIME,
    EndTime  DATETIME
)

INSERT @clientUsage (ClientName, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES 
     ('client', '2014-11-20 17:31:01.467', '2014-11-20 18:01:01.243') 
    ,('client', '2014-11-28 17:59:00.987', '2014-11-28 18:09:02.167')
    ,('client', '2014-11-28 18:00:01.403', '2014-11-28 18:25:01.443') 
    ,('client', '2014-11-29 19:13:08.580', '2014-11-30 05:30:01.763') 
    ,('client', '2014-11-30 01:55:01.953', '2014-11-30 03:54:01.730')
    ,('client 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397')
    ,('client 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397')
    ,('client 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397') 
    ,('client 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397')
    ,('client 2', '2014-12-19 23:09:01.303', '2014-12-22 09:43:01.397')
```

If you use your table instead of temp table

```
select clientname,sum(actual) from
(SELECT
    clienttime.ClientName,
    clienttime.StartTime,
    clienttime.EndTime,
    COALESCE(Actual, 0) AS Actual
FROM @clientUsage clienttime
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            D1.ClientName,
            MIN(CASE WHEN D1.StartTime < D2.StartTime THEN D1.ID ELSE D2.ID END) AS [ID],
            MIN(CASE WHEN D1.StartTime < D2.StartTime THEN D1.StartTime ELSE D2.StartTime END) AS [StartTime],
            MAX(CASE WHEN D1.EndTime > D2.EndTime THEN D1.EndTime ELSE D2.EndTime END) AS [EndTime],
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                MIN(CASE WHEN D1.StartTime < D2.StartTime THEN D1.StartTime ELSE D2.StartTime END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN D1.EndTime > D2.EndTime THEN D1.EndTime ELSE D2.EndTime END)) AS Actual
        FROM @clientUsage D1
            INNER JOIN @clientUsage D2
                ON D1.ClientName = D2.ClientName
                    AND (D1.StartTime BETWEEN D2.StartTime AND D2.EndTime
                        OR D2.StartTime BETWEEN D1.StartTime AND D1.EndTime)
        GROUP BY
            D1.ClientName,
            D1.StartTime
    ) Outages
        ON Outages.ID = clienttime.ID) op group by clientname
```

I tested in sql server.