# SQL Deduct value from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to apply total $10.00 discount for each customers.The discount should be applied to multiple transactions until all $10.00 used.
Example:

```html
CustomerID  Transaction Amount      Discount       TransactionID
1           $8.00                   $8.00          1
1           $6.00                   $2.00          2
1           $5.00                   $0.00          3
1           $1.00                   $0.00          4
2           $5.00                   $5.00          5
2           $2.00                   $2.00          6
2           $2.00                   $2.00          7
3           $45.00                  $10.00         8
3           $6.00                   $0.00          9
```

Comment: in what order should the discount be applied in?

Comment: CustomerID 3 has a discount of 10.00 and 6.00 is that incorrect?

Comment: does this table have a primary key?

Comment: JChao No,  I will edit is. Good catch.

Comment: Laurence Yes, Unique field called TransactionID.

Comment: Fuzzy Tree - The order doesn't really matter in my case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick turnaround, I am reviewing each of the solutions performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below keeps track of the running sum and calculates the discount depending on whether the running sum is greater than or less than the discount amount.

```
select 
    customerid, transaction_amount, transactionid,
    (case when 10 > (sum_amount - transaction_amount)
    then (case when transaction_amount >= 10 - (sum_amount - transaction_amount)
    then 10 - (sum_amount - transaction_amount) 
    else transaction_amount end)
    else 0 end) discount
from (
    select customerid, transaction_amount, transactionid,
    sum(transaction_amount) over (partition by customerid order by transactionid) sum_amount
    from Table1
) t1 order by customerid, transactionid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/552c2/7

same query with a self join which should work on most db's including mssql 2008

```
select 
    customerid, transaction_amount, transactionid,
    (case when 10 > (sum_amount - transaction_amount)
    then (case when transaction_amount >= 10 - (sum_amount - transaction_amount)
    then 10 - (sum_amount - transaction_amount) 
    else transaction_amount end)
    else 0 end) discount
from (
    select t1.customerid, t1.transaction_amount, t1.transactionid,
    sum(t2.transaction_amount) sum_amount
    from Table1 t1
    join Table1 t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
    and t1.transactionid >= t2.transactionid
    group by t1.customerid, t1.transaction_amount, t1.transactionid
) t1 order by customerid, transactionid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/552c2/2

Comment: I'm not sure you can `sum over order` in SQL2008, which is a shame, because this is a much better answer than mine!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with recursive common table expressions, although it isn't particularly pretty. SQL Server stuggles to optimize these types of query. See [Sum of minutes between multiple date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464281/sum-of-minutes-between-multiple-date-ranges) for some discussion.

If you wanted to go further with this approach, you'd probably need to make a temporary table of x, so you can index it on `(customerid, rn)`

```
;with x as (
  select
    tx.*,
    row_number() over (
      partition by customerid 
      order by transaction_amount desc, transactionid
    ) rn
  from
    tx
), y as (
  select
    x.transactionid,
    x.customerid,
    x.transaction_amount,
    case 
      when 10 >= x.transaction_amount then x.transaction_amount
      else 10
    end as discount,
    case 
      when 10 >= x.transaction_amount then 10 - x.transaction_amount
      else 0
    end as remainder,
    x.rn as rn
  from
    x
  where
    rn = 1
  union all
  select
    x.transactionid,
    x.customerid,
    x.transaction_amount,
    case
      when y.remainder >= x.transaction_amount then x.transaction_amount
      else y.remainder
    end,
    case
      when y.remainder >= x.transaction_amount then y.remainder - x.transaction_amount
      else 0
    end,
    x.rn
  from
    y
        inner join
    x
        on y.rn = x.rn - 1 and y.customerid = x.customerid
  where
    y.remainder > 0
)
update
  tx
set
  discount = y.discount
from
  tx
    inner join
  y
    on tx.transactionid = y.transactionid;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/944e5/1)

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to setup a test environment for such questions.  I will use a local temporary table.  Please note, I made the data un-ordered since it is not guaranteed in a real life.

```
-- play table
if exists (select 1 from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '%transactions%')
drop table #transactions
go

-- play table
create table #transactions
(
  trans_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  customer_id int,
  trans_amt smallmoney
)
go


-- add data
insert into #transactions
values
(1,$8.00),
(2,$5.00),  
(3,$45.00),     
(1,$6.00),   
(2,$2.00),     
(1,$5.00),   
(2,$2.00),   
(1,$1.00),        
(3,$6.00);      
go
```

I am going to give you two answers.

First, in 2014 there are new windows functions for rows preceding.  This allows us to get a running total (rt) and a rt adjusted by one entry.  Give these two values, we can determine if the maximum discount has been exceeded or not.

```
-- Two running totals for 2014
;
with cte_running_total 
as
(
select 
  *,

   SUM(trans_amt) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
   ORDER BY trans_id
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
   0 PRECEDING) as running_tot_p0,

   SUM(trans_amt) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
   ORDER BY trans_id
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
   1 PRECEDING) as running_tot_p1
from 
  #transactions
)
select 
   *
   ,
    case 
        when coalesce(running_tot_p1, 0) <= 10 and running_tot_p0 <= 10 then
            trans_amt 
        when coalesce(running_tot_p1, 0) <= 10 and running_tot_p0 > 10 then
            10 - coalesce(running_tot_p1, 0)
        else 0
     end as discount_amt
from cte_running_total;
```

Again, the above version is using a common table expression and advanced windowing to get the totals.

**Do not fret!**  The same can be done all the way down to SQL 2000.

Second solution, I am just going to use the order by, sub-queries, and a temporary table to store the information that is normally in the CTE.  You can switch the temporary table for a CTE in SQL 2008 if you want.

```
-- w/o any fancy functions - save to temp table
select *,
(
select count(*) from #transactions i
where i.customer_id = o.customer_id
and   i.trans_id <= o.trans_id
) as sys_rn,

(
select sum(trans_amt) from #transactions i
where i.customer_id = o.customer_id
and   i.trans_id <= o.trans_id
) as sys_tot_p0,

(
select sum(trans_amt) from #transactions i
where i.customer_id = o.customer_id
and   i.trans_id < o.trans_id
) as sys_tot_p1

into #results     
from #transactions o
order by customer_id, trans_id
go

-- report off temp table
select
    trans_id, 
    customer_id,
    trans_amt,
    case 
        when coalesce(sys_tot_p1, 0) <= 10 and sys_tot_p0 <= 10 then
            trans_amt 
        when coalesce(sys_tot_p1, 0) <= 10 and sys_tot_p0 > 10 then
            10 - coalesce(sys_tot_p1, 0)
        else 0
     end as discount_amt     
from #results
order by customer_id, trans_id
go
```

In short, your answer is show in the following screen shot.  Cut and paste the code into SSMS and have some fun.

[image]